# Python sendmail with text file content

Tags: python, smtplib

I want to send mail via python script, I need it to alert me about some missed files.

scripy have to read log file(*.txt) and send content of this file into my mail, so I made it:

```
import smtplib, os
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


raport_file = open('alert.txt','rb')
alert_msg = MIMEText(raport_file.read().encode("utf-8"), 'plain', 'utf-8')
raport_file.close()




m = smtplib.SMTP()
m.connect("*****", 25)
m.sendmail("Check_Files", "*****", alert_msg.as_string())
m.quit()
```

script run, but there is no mail at all. If I replace alert_msg.as_string() with "any text", everything works fine.

Comment: try printing `alert_msg.as_string()` and see what's the output ?

Comment: Checked your logfiles? Or are you using an external smtp host?

Comment: oh...Man, I just  checked my spam...sometimes I just do not think :) thanks for remind me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import smtplib
import base64
import os
import sys

FROM = 'user@user.com'
TO = 'user@user.com'
MARKER = 'SIMPLE_MARKER_GOES_HERE'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = 'name_of_file'

    # Read a file and encode it into base64 format
    fo = open(filename, "rb")
    filecontent = fo.read()
    encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)  # base64
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)

    body ="""
Insert whatever message you want here or dynamically create.
"""

    # Define the main headers.
    part1 = """From: Matt Vincent <matt.vincent@jax.org>
To: %s
Subject: Sending Attachment
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s
--%s
""" % (TO, MARKER, MARKER)

    # Define the message action
    part2 = """Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

%s
--%s
""" % (body, MARKER)

    # Define the attachment section
    part3 = """Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s

%s
--%s--
""" %(filename, filename, encodedcontent, MARKER)

    message = part1 + part2 + part3

    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('domainhere')
        smtpObj.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        print "Successfully sent email"
    except Exception:
        print "Error: unable to send email"
```